# Google Apps Script PropertiesService Permissions for AddOns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I'm currently developing an Editor Add-on for Google Sheets using Apps Script. There's an `onOpen` function that sets up the menu items.

I also have a CONFIG variable in the root (not in any function) like this:

```js
const CONFIG = {}

function setProperties_(){
  CONFIG.tmpSheetId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('TMP_SHEET_ID');
  
}

setProperties_();
```

If I run any functions from within the script editor, everything runs fine. No issues. However, when I do a test deployment I get the error below from the moment the `onOpen()` runs:

```
You do not have permission to call getScriptProperties
```

I've tried adding various script scopes from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes) but nothing works.

Comment: Hi Riaz, It will be really helpful if you can share the `OnOpen()` function you are using

Comment: I would call `config` a global variable.   And the way that you left the function invocation of `setProperties_()` in global space means that every time you make any function call in the project you are also calling setProperties().  Which may be part of your problem.   I wish I could help you more but I know coding reasonably well but not so much some of the higher level theory.  Sorry.  Hope one of the other volunteers can be of more assistance to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first install the add-on (the entry for the add-on becomes visible in the sheet menu), it runs in AuthMode.NONE that allows you to inspect only the current user's locale. Please refer to the table here  [Google Add-On Authorization Lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle)

As Cooper pointed out, calling setProperties_() in global scope occurs before your add-on is authorized by the user. Move the function call to a nested function and make sure you are through with the authorization flow first.